interacting with function from unpublished contract
[
    {
        "from": "0xb9407830d585511d96e5dfff4646758a01aef59b",
        "topic": "0xc7055204ed36db5349d262f15f91b6cc7ad9a35590718297a887419f77217e9b",
        "event": "Response",
        "args": {
            "0": true,
            "1": "Call this contract with function signature '0xddc24be3' providing a 'uint256' argument of value: 39013626048177875853997655488989711994093844045072180110515763197087137086347 Also send some wei: 420007094035",
            "success": true,
            "decodedData": "Call this contract with function signature '0xddc24be3' providing a 'uint256' argument of value: 39013626048177875853997655488989711994093844045072180110515763197087137086347 Also send some wei: 420007094035"
        } 

I have managed to interact with a view function from a smart contract that is not verified or published, the data from the view function is pasted above and asking me to call another function and includes two inputs that need to be executed also. Could someone explain how I could interact with this function?
I have tried to use json rpc but am having trouble

Whta is the context of this? The question does not have enough details to understand why you are doing and what you are expecting.

i am trying to interact with the function 0xddc24be3 and input the uint256 parameter and also send the contract the requested amount of wei, im doing a puzzle and this is the second part of it. This out put is from the view function i interacted with from a smart contract and decoded the message had this request to interact with said function. the outcome to is get the transaction hash from these interactions
